# Framework for paint program

Tags: python, linux, qt, gtk

I've decided to start working on a personal project, attempting to develop a cross platform, MSPaint like app.  Oddly enough, I find mspaint is one of the applications I miss the most on Linux or OS X, so I want to try to make something similar.  Tuxpaint, mtpaint, gpaint, etc. are all old and inactive and ugly.  I don't want to make GIMP, just the basics, similar in features to MS Paint.

I'm thinking of doing it in python with the pygtk toolkit, but I was interested to hear your suggestions.  Would C/C++ be a better choice, or even C# (gasp!) with mono?  How about using Qt as opposed to GTK, or maybe some other fancy library I don't know about (Please, not FLTK!).  I'd be curious to hear your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use *Gimp* or more simply *Inkscape* under Linux. And LibreOffice has some drawing abilities too.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch none of these tools has the primitive simplicity of notepad. If anything `gpaint` is the most paint-like I've seen.

Comment: Sometimes you just want to crop an image, add a piece of text, or scribble around for fun.  GIMP and Inkscape are overkill. gpaint was last modified in 2000, so it's dated.  I think this will be a fun project, though it probably won't pan out.

Comment: Why "Please, not FLTK!"? Of all toolkits mentioned, it is the easiest and fastest...

Answer (score 3):

Qt's canvas object (or its newer replacement QGraphicsView) can do pretty cool things. Whether you choose C++ or python is a matter of personal choice, as Qt is supported in both languages. For a simple project like this I'd choose python because killer performance is not much of an issue, and it will be much easier to write.

Another thing to look into is making this app web based with HTML5's canvas object and Javascript. It can be surprisingly robust, and anything that can be put on the cloud is a win in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with Python (which would be my choice because it's such a simple language), then TkInter is considered the [de-facto standard GUI package](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). That link should send you to some excellent starting references for TkInter, although I also really like Not_a_Golfer's suggestion of an HTML5 web-app.

Comment: I haven't tried tkinter yet, and most of my Qt programming was in C++, but it was hands down the best C++ API for _anything_ I've ever worked with. How are tkinter's canvas abilities? BTW SDL would also be an option here, but probably an overkill.

Comment: I'm not the best person to answer that I'm afraid as I mainly use Python for text-processing rather than GUI work. I recommended TkInter simply as the 'Pythonic' choice. Perhaps someone with more GUI experience than me can add a comment addressing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Short: You can use both, no third party library is guaranteed to be distributed with all major distributions.

Long:

Gtk+ vs. Qt

- What do you want incorporate into your application. If it is just selecting a brush, selecting color you could pretty much use any gui toolkit.
- If you are going to run it as a web-based tool, Gtk+ has an html5 backend renderer (I don't know about Qt)

A sidenote:
I recommend to use the toolkit's native programming language (gtk+ C, Qt C++) - if you don't, you will suffer from delays with bugfixes, generally more bugs and delayed releases, though for that case it shouldn't really matter.

**Everything else boils down to personal preferences and there already exist some questions to tackling that issue.**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using qt,you can use [QtitanRibbon](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4214)